# Get all records from master table and matching from child using WHERE mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two table in my MySQL table: 
`1) mast_checkup (master)` 
`2) tbl_lab_checkup (child)`

Table structure is as follow: 
`1) mast_checkup:`

-- checkid (pk) 
-- title 
-- description

`2) tbl_lab_checkup`

-- labcheckupid(pk) 
-- labid(fk) 
-- mastcheckupid(fk) 
-- discount 
-- cost

I want to show all the records from master table and all records from child table where labid='1
I tried following query.

```
SELECT * FROM mast_checkup mc
LEFT JOIN tbl_lab_checkup tlc ON
mc.checkupid=tlc.mastcheckupid WHERE
tlc.ladid=1
```

Couldn't get exact result.

**What I need is all records from patent table and matching from child and if no match found from child it should result all master fields and null child fields**

Required Result

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
checkid | title   | labcheckupid| labid | discount | cost
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    |title 1  |    1    |1      |  5       | 1500

   2    |title 2  |    NULL |NULL   |NULL      |    NULL
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

first is a records which is in both master and child table
and second one is only in master but not in child

Any solutions for this requirement ?

Comment: I don't see these two keys,`mc.checkupid` and `tlc.mastcheckupid`, in your table schema

Comment: What I need is all records from patent table and matching from child and if no match found from child it should result all master fields and null child fields

Comment: Where is the `patent` table? and what do you mean by exact results? What results are you getting?

Comment: check fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e33375

Comment: What I need is all records from patent table and matching from child and if no match found from child it should result all master fields and null child fields

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need..

```
SELECT * FROM mast_checkup mc
LEFT JOIN tbl_lab_checkup tlc ON mc.checkid=tlc.mastcheckupid
AND tlc.labid=1
```